# Correct linebreaking on comment text for sidecaption using memoir class

Tags: captions, line-breaking, memoir, sidecap

I use some tricks to have a good `\sidecaption` command for the memoir class.

But how can i have a correct separation between title name and some possible comments on the figure ?

> **Figure 1.1** : My figure title
>
> blablablabla

I try to insert another `caption` block in `sidecaption`, without success :/

Here, the MWE :

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt,twoside, openright]{memoir}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\captionnamefont{\bfseries}
\sidecapmargin{outer}
\setsidecappos{t}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\fnum@figure}[1]{\textbf{\figurename~\thefigure:} }
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{sidecaption}[fortoc]{ Vue d'ensemble des algorithmes d'optimisation selon Weise}[fig:S_OverviewOptimisation]
  \centering
 \includegraphics[width=.9\linewidth]{overview_optimisation_algorithm.png}
  \end{sidecaption}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add some vertical space manually in the caption, for example `\\[2ex]`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, twoside, openright]{memoir}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\captionnamefont{\bfseries}
\sidecapmargin{outer}
\setsidecappos{t}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]

   \begin{sidecaption}[Overview Optimisation]{%
         My figure title\\[2ex]               % <--- Added vertical space here. 
         Vue d'ensemble des algorithmes d'optimisation selon Weise
      }[fig:S_OverviewOptimisation]
      \centering
      \includegraphics[width=.9\linewidth]{overview_optimisation_algorithm.png}
   \end{sidecaption}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Maybe you should increase the marginwidth or reduce the fontsize, in order to make the sidecaption look more pleasing.